# How can I achieve installing apks from server like android market?

Tags: android, sql-server

I am in the middle of developing an application when I had this idea to allow some applications to be installed in the android device only through a server.
Now I am short of ideas on how to approach this.
An Example of what I want to achieve is the android market website that when you login and synchronize your device, you can see the different applications that you have already installed in your device and also you can install applications onto your device without the application asking for permission to install.

Please if anyone has any idea or a good suggestion as to how I can accomplish this task (both for the server and the android codes) I would so appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, on non-rooted phones or ROMs that you don't fully control it is not possible to install an .apk in the background without user interaction.

If however you decide to only target rooted phones or you have your own custom ROM on which this would work, it is just a matter of sending apps to the phone, and then installing them, for which you can find all the code you need in the Android OS source-code.

Comment: But I have a Galaxy S2 which is not rooted and which I synchronized with my account in android market and I can install applications directly to my phone from the marketplace website. How would you explain this? How is it possible if my device is and never was rooted? Would love to hear your answer please.

Comment: You need control over 2 elements to be able to accomplish that: the server, and the phone's OS. Google controls both, and this is why it can do that.

Comment: Ok. So does it mean that even if I have a server with these applications source(apks) I can not still be able to acomplish it?

Comment: yes. Amazon, SlideMe and all other third-party stores have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks.But does it mean there is no other way to approach or workaround this without rooting?